# Cannot bind parameter because parameter 'AccountPassword' is specified more than once ,how to fix this issue, thanks

Tags: powershell

Import-Module activedirectory
$ADUsers = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Script\CreateUser.Mass\20190527.Wave.csv"
foreach ($User in $ADUsers)
{

```
$GivenName = $User.'GivenName'            
$Surname = $User.'Surname'            
$Displayname = $User.'DisplayName' 
$Title = $User.'Title'            
$Department = $User.'Department'
$Office = $User.'Office'
$Company = $User.'Company'
$StreetAddress = $User.'StreetAddress'
$City = $User.'City'
$Country = $User.'Country'
$HomePage = $User.'HomePage'
$Password = $User.'Password'          

$SAM = $User.'SamAccountName'            
$OU = "OU=Users-Massimport,OU=SITA-HK,DC=swiresita,DC=com"            
$UPN = $User.'DisplayName' + "@swiresita.com" 


New-ADUser  -Name "$Displayname" -GivenName "$GivenName" -Surname "$Surname" -Displayname "$Displayname" -Title "$Title" -Department "$Department" -Office "$Office" -Company "$Company" -StreetAddress  "$StreetAddress" -City "$City" -Country "$Country" -HomePage "$HomePage" -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force) -SamAccountName $SAM -UserPrincipalName $UPN -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force) -Enabled $true -Path "$OU" -ChangePasswordAtLogon $false -PasswordNeverExpires $false
```

}

Comment: you have that parameter shown TWICE ... so remove the 2nd one? [*grin*]

Comment: I would recommend [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) as it makes things much simpler, particularly with a large number of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [Bill_Stewart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2102693/bill-stewart) in the comments, use [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-6):

```
foreach ($User in $ADUsers)
{

    $adUserParameters  = @{ 
        GivenName = $User.'GivenName'            
        Surname = $User.'Surname'            
        Displayname = $User.'DisplayName' 
        Title = $User.'Title'            
        Department = $User.'Department'
        Office = $User.'Office'
        Company = $User.'Company'
        StreetAddress = $User.'StreetAddress'
        City = $User.'City'
        Country = $User.'Country'
        HomePage = $User.'HomePage'
        Password = $User.'Password'          
        SAM = $User.'SamAccountName'            
        OU = "OU=Users-Massimport,OU=SITA-HK,DC=swiresita,DC=com"            
        UPN = ($User.'DisplayName' + "@swiresita.com")
        AccountPassword = (ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force)
        Enabled = $true
        ChangePasswordAtLogon = $false
        PasswordNeverExpires = $false
    }


    New-ADUser @adUserParameters 
}
```

If you're on an older version of powershell you can use '`' (grave sign) to add a new line while continuing the call to New-AdUser:

```
New-ADUser  `
    -Name "$Displayname" `
    -GivenName "$GivenName" `
    -Surname "$Surname" `
    -Displayname "$Displayname" `
    -Title "$Title" `
    -Department "$Department" `
    -Office "$Office" `
    -Company "$Company" `
    -StreetAddress  "$StreetAddress" `
    -City "$City" `
    -Country "$Country" `
    -HomePage "$HomePage" `
    -SamAccountName $SAM `
    -UserPrincipalName $UPN `
    -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force) `
    -Enabled $true `
    -Path "$OU" `
    -ChangePasswordAtLogon $false `
    -PasswordNeverExpires $false
```

Comment: "Older" in this context means "older than version 2." PowerShell 2.0 is a core component on Windows 7/Server 2008 R2. Splatting was introduced in version 2.